# Flex Contents wont Align in a Row Horizontally (Bootstrap 5)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

My Images seems to be not aligning in a Horizontal Row, I Tried every method but not working :(

Output:
[image: Output of the HTML and CSS]

```css
.img-size-square {
    width:  100%;
    height:  auto;
    max-width: 400px !important;
    max-height: 400px !important;
}

.container-for-hover {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image-for-hover {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay-for-hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #6633ff;
}

.container-for-hover:hover .overlay-for-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text-for-hover {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="d-flex col-12">
        <div class="mx-auto">
          <div class="container-for-hover img-size-square mb-2">
            <img class="image-for-hover" src="http://jazzfu.000webhostapp.com/upload/placeholder-sq.webp">
            <div class="overlay-for-hover">
              <div class="text-for-hover">Some Content Here 1, Row 1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-for-hover img-size-square mb-2">
            <img class="image-for-hover" src="http://jazzfu.000webhostapp.com/upload/placeholder-sq.webp">
            <div class="overlay-for-hover">
              <div class="text-for-hover">Some Content Here 2, Row 1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-for-hover img-size-square mb-2">
            <img class="image-for-hover" src="http://jazzfu.000webhostapp.com/upload/placeholder-sq.webp">
            <div class="overlay-for-hover">
              <div class="text-for-hover">Some Content Here 3, Row 1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="d-flex col-12">
        <div class="mx-auto">
          <div class="container-for-hover img-size-square mb-2">
            <img class="image-for-hover" src="http://jazzfu.000webhostapp.com/upload/placeholder-sq.webp">
            <div class="overlay-for-hover">
              <div class="text-for-hover">Some Content Here 1, Row 2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-for-hover img-size-square mb-2">
            <img class="image-for-hover" src="http://jazzfu.000webhostapp.com/upload/placeholder-sq.webp">
            <div class="overlay-for-hover">
              <div class="text-for-hover">Some Content Here 2, Row 2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-for-hover img-size-square mb-2">
            <img class="image-for-hover" src="http://jazzfu.000webhostapp.com/upload/placeholder-sq.webp">
            <div class="overlay-for-hover">
              <div class="text-for-hover">Some Content Here 3, Row 2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

What I Tried:
I Tried everything on the Official Docs and on here -> [W3 BS5 Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_flex.php), I Tried also `flex-row`, I'm also new to Web Developing Field.

Goal:
The `container-for-image` Div(s) should be Placed in a Horizontal Row in each `row` class div

Answer (score 1):

just use flex on class mx-auto

```css
.img-size-square {
    width:  100%;
    height:  auto;
    max-width: 400px !important;
    max-height: 400px !important;
}

.container-for-hover {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image-for-hover {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay-for-hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #6633ff;
}

.container-for-hover:hover .overlay-for-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text-for-hover {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.mx-auto{
display:flex;
margin:0 auto;


}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="d-flex col-12">
        <div class="mx-auto">
          <div class="container-for-hover img-size-square mb-2">
            <img class="image-for-hover" src="http://jazzfu.000webhostapp.com/upload/placeholder-sq.webp">
            <div class="overlay-for-hover">
              <div class="text-for-hover">Some Content Here 1, Row 1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-for-hover img-size-square mb-2">
            <img class="image-for-hover" src="http://jazzfu.000webhostapp.com/upload/placeholder-sq.webp">
            <div class="overlay-for-hover">
              <div class="text-for-hover">Some Content Here 2, Row 1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-for-hover img-size-square mb-2">
            <img class="image-for-hover" src="http://jazzfu.000webhostapp.com/upload/placeholder-sq.webp">
            <div class="overlay-for-hover">
              <div class="text-for-hover">Some Content Here 3, Row 1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="d-flex col-12">
        <div class="mx-auto">
          <div class="container-for-hover img-size-square mb-2">
            <img class="image-for-hover" src="http://jazzfu.000webhostapp.com/upload/placeholder-sq.webp">
            <div class="overlay-for-hover">
              <div class="text-for-hover">Some Content Here 1, Row 2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-for-hover img-size-square mb-2">
            <img class="image-for-hover" src="http://jazzfu.000webhostapp.com/upload/placeholder-sq.webp">
            <div class="overlay-for-hover">
              <div class="text-for-hover">Some Content Here 2, Row 2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-for-hover img-size-square mb-2">
            <img class="image-for-hover" src="http://jazzfu.000webhostapp.com/upload/placeholder-sq.webp">
            <div class="overlay-for-hover">
              <div class="text-for-hover">Some Content Here 3, Row 2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot, i was breaking my head for 4 lines of code

Comment: can i close a question here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the 3 children as *direct* children of the `d-flex` container, since that is the flex container. The way you have it, `d-flex` is trying to put only `mx-auto` into a row (resulting in a row of 1 div).

```html
 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="d-flex col-12 mx-auto">
        <div class="container-for-hover img-size-square mb-2">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="container-for-hover img-size-square mb-2">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="container-for-hover img-size-square mb-2">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).